# Remote branch in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

As you can see, I checked checkBox 'show remote branches, but in a list, there are only local branches. I have to uncheck and check checkBox to show remote branches.

So the interesting thing. I use two projects (project A and project B). When I work with project A(current project), it works like in the picture. But if I work in project B, it works fine, and all remote branches are shown.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-173.4548.28

Please, someone, explain to me, why works so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a bug. It is planned to remove the checkbox, so the issue to follow is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144948

Comment: Thank you,  now I can sleep)